# how to make triangle in css

Tags: html, css

I have this problem: i am not a design person. i just simply dont know how to make this arrow under the rectangle:

[image]

i tried to make a div with this background color and hang some image under it, but i am trying to do this for 2 hours now and i am totally stuck not finding a image tool which cuts out in triangle form. then i decided to do this thru css, but cannot somehow do it.

how can i do this triangle in css and hang to div? i want that if i resize window, the triangle should stick to div and doesnot move.

many many thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6CtWz/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
```

**css**

```
.arrow-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6CtWz/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1"><div class="arrow-down"></div></div>
```

**css**

```
#div1{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#f00;
}
.arrow-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
    position:absolute; //added position:absolute
}
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.arrow-down').css('top', $('#div1').height() + 5).css('left', '20px');
});
```

or you can make use of `:after` only css effect

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6CtWz/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p>Testing triangle</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #f00;
    position: relative;
}
div:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, so how can i make that arrow stick to parent div?

Comment: check updated demo..!!

Comment: great! working like a charm! thanks

Comment: @doniyor, I too made one http://jsbin.com/asejem/1/